# How to assign anchor tag id to asp-route-id in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Below are the anchor tags, which has to call controller action on its click event with dynamic parameters.

One of the dynamic parameter value is "viewdata" based ie, "asp-route-itemUrl" attribute

Where as the second dynamic parameter value is based on the corresponding control custom attribute i.e, "asp-route-item-id" attribute.

**Question:**
How to get value of custom attribute "item-id" of  tag & assign to another property "asp-route-itemId' of same  tag?

asp-route-itemId="$(this).attr('item-id')" => *not working*, 'item-id' attribute value *not assigned* to "asp-route-itemId" attribute

```
  <a item-id="item1" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Order" asp-route-itemId="$(this).attr('item-id')" asp-route-itemUrl="@ViewData["itemUrl1"]">Order1</a>


  <a item-id="item2" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Order" asp-route-itemId="$(this).attr('item-id')" asp-route-itemUrl="@ViewData["itemUrl2"]">Order2</a>
```

Comment: What does your route definition look like? Does it have an `itemId` route parameter? The `asp-route-{key}` must align with the route parameter name in order to construct a URL to that route.

Comment: @JeremyCaney, route is working fine. No problem with route. Question is how to assign value "item1" - the value of "item-id" attribute to "asp-route-itemId" attribute of same anchor tag?